# Serial Port Communication with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

[want to get this firmware like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zWtN.png)

[Graph data output protocol start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpndu.png)

I want to communicate with a serial port and get data. Now I already configured the port and start my program and it is running. The hardware is sending every time data, but without any changes as You can see here ( just ABC.. is changing and the number before):

> 0+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   1+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   2+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   3+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   4+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   5+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   6+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   7+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   8+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   9+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   A+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   B+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   C+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   D+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   E+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   F+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTB
>   0+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   1+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   2+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   3+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   4+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   5+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   6+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   7+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   8+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   9+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   A+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   B+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   C+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   D+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   E+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC
>   F+00000E-02+000000E-03  A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC

The technical sheet says:

All data sets for parameter protocol starts with an STX(02H) ends with an ETX(03H) characters.
If I try to send a command as I can see in the technical sheet, for example:

**GET firm Version (0x00-0xFF is Dummy = DD):**

**STX | 'V' | 'G' | DD | EXT**

> - STX :0x02
> - 'V' :0x56
> - 'G' :0x47
> - DD  :0x00-0xFF
> - EXT :0x03

I can´t see any changes, as I can read in the manual for these command as the resulting answer is:

> - STX :0x02
> - 'V' :0x56
> - 'G' :0x47
> - TTTTTTTTTTTT:'V1.00.00'
> - DD  :0x00-0xFF
> - EXT :0x03
>
> Where TTTTTTTTTTTT= Version string, 16 characters.

Before, I read in this context in a other question that the dummy is for checksum, but until now, I have not any answer how to take it in a code. But I think it is like this (?):

```
 Dim DD As IEnumerable(Of Byte) = New Byte() {&H0, &HFF}
```

And for search the Firmware it looks:

```
Dim stx As Boolean = False

        Dim etx As Boolean = False


        Try
            For i As Int32 = 0 To BytesToRead

                Dim Incoming As Integer = ReadByte()

                Dim c As Char = ChrW(Incoming)

                If Incoming.Equals(&H2) Then
                    stx = True


                    Continue For
                ElseIf Incoming = &H3 Then
                    etx = True

                End If

            Next




        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

And for the command:

Dim STX As Byte = &H2
    Dim ETX As Byte = &H3

```
Dim buf As Byte() = {STX, &H56, &H47, &HFF, ETX}

serialport.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length)
```

1. How can I get the answer above as I can see in the manual?
2. If I have to write handshake (no info in manual) how to do?
3. The hardware is a transducer, if I take it in action there is nothing in
   change in the data above, as you can see. The support has said, that I can get all data embedded between these characters like above (STX..EXT) but there is nothing like these.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you are saying that if you send `STX | 'V' | 'G' | DD | EXT` (ignoring spaces and vertical bars as well I assume) it should respond with `STX | 'V' | 'G' | TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT | DD | EXT`? But you get no response? And is it expecting you to send a true checksum in DD or is that only really used in the response?

Comment: Exactly, I try to send the code as you have said, but the hardware/serial port doesn´t respond as you have said. I don´t know, whether the serial port expect the Dummy as checksum, because the manual is saying you have to send it as hex between the value as you can see above. That I have to use "checksum" for it, I have see in this forum. But I don't know whether and how...

Comment: We can figure out the checksum in a bit. What command are you using to get all the data you showed at the top? Or does it always output it? Is the manual for this transducer online?

Comment: It is always output it and the manual (there are a few manuals) says in chapter "Graph Data output protocol" or I can read it, that this are the dataset for the graph. And there is an example that let me know that´s the graph protocol, because it says start begins with '6H' and ends with '08H' as I can read it if I loop it in a byte array for each character.

Comment: I´m underlining that there are more than one data sheet, and I want to know how can I communicate with the serial port to get for example the firmware, as I can read in chapter " parameter protocol" in the manual. Now I show you the examples from the manual as picture in the top of my question.(Manual isn´t online)

Comment: Sorry, going to be too busy to help for a while, but the manual says the checksum isn't used for sending or retrieving so that isn't your issue. I assume your search for firmware code above is in the DataRecieved event. If you put a breakpoint on the For statement and step through what bytes is it sending back?

Comment: It is sending continuous. Now I find out, that the code above is the graph protocol, because it is changing in some of these characters, if I manipulate the transducer. In case of your question, there are permanent bytes, so if I´m looking with the Debug modus, I can see Chw(6) and if I cut the end of line with newline it is the string above "A+00000E-03+00000E-03+041743E-0111000TTC F+00000E-02+000000E-03". It is sending back beginning with 6 byte than changing etcetera. How can I look explicit to the data receive after sending command ( command is correct?) ?

Comment: So is there an ending character for what you are calling the "graph protocol"? Or is it always 44 bytes long? It seems very odd that they might send a response to a version command in the middle of another response. I could see where maybe one block of graph data would end then it would have a block for version data and then the next block of graph data would begin. Or maybe there is a command to stop the graph data from being sent while you send other commands. Anyway, you would be looking for STX and then an ETX. Unlike what you have now, you only look for ETX if you already have STX.

Comment: Yes there is an ending, but I couldn't add the last picture with the end (08H) because I´m not having enough rights in this forum for more than 2 pictures. I took a look for the getting characters above, and tried other characters like the graph data protocol and I compared with the manual, than I was sure it is the graph data protocol. So I will looking as soon as possible again. But I already looked for STX/EXT as you can see in the try catch block, or in which form you would like or suggest to search for STX/EXT?

Comment: Receiving data should all be done in the DataReceived event of the port. Stuff it into a buffer then you could have anothe rthread checking the buffer for particular characters that start a message (eg, 06 or 02). If you find one then you look for the corresponding closing character. Once you find that, you pull all those characters out of the buffer and process them however you need to.

Comment: After some unsuccessful attempts I hope to get some more helpful information. Until now, I can´t get out the firmware as I can see in the manual. So I already tried these commands: `If nGineric.IsOpen Then
          Dim s As String = ChrW(&H2) & ChrW(&H56) & ChrW(&H47) & ChrW(&H0) & ChrW(&H3)
            nGineric.Write(s)
        End If` and also: `Dim buf As Byte() = {&H2, &H56, &H47, &HF,&H3}       If nGineric.IsOpen Then
            nGineric.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length)
        End If`

Comment: However I think it is a failed attempt in sending by port.write() maybe not the right semantic?

Comment: Another thing I'd try (not tested) is `Write(Chr(2) & "VG00" & Chr(3))`. If that doesn't work, I think your best bet is calling the company's tech support.

Comment: Thanks, I already solved my problem with tech support. For additional information: there isn´t a dummy byte but therefore is a two byte code like: `Dim STX As Byte = &H2
        Dim ETX As Byte = &H3

        Dim buf As Byte() = {STX, &H57, &H47, &H30, &H30, ETX}` and than I get for these example the firmware.

Comment: Last but not least ;) how to code a Buffer exactly? There is a Class of Buffer in vb.net, may I have to use it for a Buffer ?

Comment: I had noticed you were only doing one byte in those recent examples which is why I had 00 in my string, but you had used FF before, which should have been 2 bytes but I guess it was truncated. Been too long since I've dealt with this. Glad you finally got it!

Comment: I've not looked into the Buffer Class that I recall yet. I just use a variable to hold whatever I receive until it can be processed. Whatever you receive gets appended to the end of it. You then look for complete messages (eg, STX with ETX) from the start of it. If you find a message you remove that message from the variable so it doesn't get reprocessed. If you are using threads, you may need to do some extra locking so the variable is thread-safe.

Comment: Now I want to write the data in a global Buffer, but it is caused pain because there is a Buffer class in vb.net for ? However, how to write a global variable to hold whatever is received ?

Comment: Here is a serial port example with using threads and a buffer, but read the whole thread as there is good info elsewhere, too. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?761597-VB-2010-Express-Serial-port-threading-problem&p=4657951&viewfull=1#post4657951

Comment: Thanks, but how to write parameter number in 4-digit and 8-digit notation, when the 4-digit has to be 0x0002 and for the 8-digit to be 1?

Comment: Not sure which parameter you are talking about, but surely Google will find the answers for you. I'm too busy now.